# Converting escaped unicode characters to unicode notation

Tags: python, unicode

I have a pickle file that when read contains the escaped unicode characters.
If I print the string, it gives the following output as `catu\u1e63\u1e6daya` and is stored as a `str` type.
If I print the same character by character, I get the following.

```
c
a
t
u
\
u
1
e
6
3
\
u
1
e
6
d
a
y
a
```

I have tried `decode`, `encode` and `de-encode` methods. I have also tried the `unicode` method as well. Is there any way to retrieve the exact information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*decode* using  [`"unicode-escape"`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
s.decode("unicode-escape")
```

Which gives you:

```
In [17]: print s.decode("raw_unicode_escape")
catuṣṭaya
```